# JTC ignores URDF velocity limit

Tags: ros2, ros2-control, joint-trajectory-controller, ros2-controllers

having setup my igus axis to control it with the joint_trajectory controller it seems that it completely ignores any limits i set in the urdf file.
Is there a fix for this?

urdf joint:

```xml
  <joint name="${prefix}joint1" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="${prefix}base_link"/>
    <child link="${prefix}link1"/>
<origin xyz="0 ${width1y/2} ${height2/2}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
    <limit lower="0" upper="2" velocity=".05" effort="10"/> 

  </joint>
```

controller:

````yaml
joint_trajectory_position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - axis_joint1


    command_interfaces:
      - velocity

    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

    state_publish_rate: 200.0 # Defaults to 50
    action_monitor_rate: 20.0 # Defaults to 20
    gains:
      axis_joint1:
        p: 0.5
        i: 0.0
        d: 0.0
        i_clamp: 0.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
    allow_partial_joints_goal: true # Defaults to false
    open_loop_control: false
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JTC does not support that yet. You have to consider that while planning the trajectory which you send to it.